# strongly-typed resources with custom CultureInfo

Tags: c#, .net, resources

I want both
 a) **explicitly specify CultureInfo at run-time** and
 b) **use strongly-typed resource properties** or **strongly-typed keys**.

I mean something like this:

```
Properties.GetResourcesForCultureInfo(user.CultureInfo).MyResourceFile.MyString;
```

Or

```
Properties.MyResourceFile.ResourceSet.GetString(MyResourceFile.MyStringKey, user.CultureInfo);
```

Is it possible to implement?

Comment: Is it an option to set the culture via `Thread`? Then things will work as intended.

Comment: @Patko, unfortunately no, because thread language is not the same as user language.